# Why is my state only updated on the second state change instead of first state change with useEffect in React?

Tags: reactjs, state

I made a search bar that allows the user to search all sports available in one specific city (if sport is not defined) or a specific sport in a specific city (if sport is defined).
City will allways be defined.

I put 2 inputs (city and sport) on my searchbar and I want immediate results (so that there is a request to my API without any button "search" that triggers the request).

So when the user types something on the city input it triggers a request to the API and when he types something on the sport input it retriggers the request but this time with the city and the sport defined.
Both inputs values are store in states (city and sport).

I manage to do something that seems to work, the only problem is that if I types a sport in my input search, it does not update my request to the API. I have to retype the sport in my input a second time so that the request is updated.
I don't know why it does not update the first time I types something in my sport input because I have specified on my useEffect array that it must re render when the sport state changes.

Can someone help me understand this ?

My code :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import style from "../styles/pdrs.module.css";
import axios from "axios";


import SearchBar from "../components/SearchBar";

const Pdrs = ({ setSearchCity, searchSport, setSearchSport }) => {
  // if request's result is loading
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  // search result
  const [searchresults, setSearchresults] = useState(
    "Lancez une recherche avec au moins une ville !"
  );
  // state for the searchbar request
  const [city, setCity] = useState("");
  const [sport, setSport] = useState(0);

  // get city's id for API's request
  const fetchCity = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
      // city search
      const cityResponse = await axios.get(
        `${baseAPI}/city/name=${searchCity}`
      );
      const city = cityResponse.data;
      setCity(city);
      setIsLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

  //fetching sport id
  const fetchSport = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
      const sportResponse = await axios.get(
        `${baseAPI}/activity/name=${searchSport}`
      );
      setSport(sportResponse.data.data[0].macro_activity_id);
      setIsLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  };

  //fetching final request response
  const fetchDataRequest = async () => {
    try {
      setIsLoading(true);
      const results = await axios.get(
        `${baseAPI}/pdrs?city_id=${city.id}${
          sport ? "&macro_activity_id=" + sport : ""
        }`
      );
      // manage search results
      if (results.data.nb_results === 1) {
        setSearchresults({
          data: [results.data.data],
          nb_results: 1,
        });
        setNbResults(1);
        setIsLoading(false);
      } else {
        setSearchresults(results.data);
        setNbResults(results.data.nb_results);
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
      setSearchresults(
        "Sorry, nothing was found... !"
      );
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (searchCity) {
      fetchCity();
    }
    if (searchSport) {
      fetchSport();
    }
  }, [searchCity, searchSport]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (searchCity) {
      fetchDataRequest();
    }
  }, [searchCity, searchSport]);
  console.log(searchresults);
  return <>
    <main className={`container ${style.pdrs}`}>
      <section className={style.searchbar}>
        <SearchBar
          searchCity={searchCity}
          setSearchCity={setSearchCity}
          searchSport={searchSport}
          setSearchSport={setSearchSport}
          searchInstallation={searchInstallation}
          setSearchInstallation={setSearchInstallation}
          searchType={searchType}
          setSearchType={setSearchType}
          setPage={setPage}
        />
      </section>
      <section className={style.results}>
        {isLoading ? (
          <div>Loading...</div>
        ) : typeof searchresults === "string" ? (
          <div className={`${style.container} ${style.noResults}`}>
            <h2>{searchresults}</h2>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <>
            <div className={style.container}>
              <div className={style.resultsList}>
                {searchresults.data.map((pdrs) => {
                  return (
                 // some code displaying the result
                  );
                })}
              </div>
            </div>
          </>
        )}
      </section>
    </main>
</>;
};

export default Pdrs;
```

Comment: Can you please share more code including the rest of this component?

Comment: I edited my post.

Comment: It would be ideal if you can make codesandbox and present the possible error. So make working code there. From this code, this should be working. But you have that SearchBar component and that may be of interest

Comment: My searchbar has an autocomplete and sets the city and sport states.
The code is working, if I type a city in the input city, it returns the API result with all the sports available for that city (so it is working) but if I type a sport in the sport's input, the request stays the same as before (only the city result) and I have to retype the sport in the input (without refreshing the page) so that the new result is updated (result with the specified city and specified sport).
And I don't understand why the request does not update the first time I type something in the sport input.

Comment: Maybe instead of listening for `[searchCity, searchSport]` for useEffect where you call `fetchDataRequest`, you listen to `[city, sport]`?

Comment: I just tried that but it makes an infinite loop. I retried my code. I type the city, get the result for just the city. Then I type the sport, still stays on previous result but if I start to delete the word on my sport input, even just the last character of the word, the result states update to the correct request (city + sport). 
I still don't know why it does not update immediately when I type the word.

Comment: I might have found something. When I console.log sport (to show the id to do the request) sometimes it is equal to 0. So I think the final request is send before the previous request that catches the sport id (needed for the final request).
How can I put an order in my requests ? So that it first do the sport request and then the final request ? 
Can I put a priority in useEffect ?

Comment: Well implicitly the order in which you position useEffect will determin how it fires. So first is first and second is second. 
And since you have debouncing idea there i suggest you use useDebouncedCallback from https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-debounce lib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are having two `useEffect` and one is setting `city` and `sport` you would need to make debounce for making a call for fetching list by itself.

I would suggest that you firstly make changes to your use effect for API call `fetchDataRequest`:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (searchCity) {
    fetchDataRequest();
  }
}, [city, sport]);
```

You would listen to the actual data from BE, not from input that you fill.

And secondly you can use library `useDebounce` from here https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-debounce and use `useDebounceCallback` to delay calling API call after you select sport/city.